# laravel 4 does not work on Windows XAMPP

Tags: php, windows-7, laravel, xampp, laravel-4

On Windows 7 cmd I have run `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist` from `C:\xampp\htdocs\lara. Everything is downloaded and installed fine.

However, when I try to access `http://localhost/lara/blog` it shows the directory listing of apache. I followed the instruction in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation) during the installation.

I noticed the following notes:

1. `C:\xampp\htdocs\lara\blog` does not has any index.php or .htaccess
2. `C:\xampp\htdocs\lara\blog\app` also, does not has any index.php or .htaccess
3. Only accessing `http://localhost/lara/blog/public` opens a page with the laravel logo and the words "You have arrived"

I could not able to know what's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel's folder structure uses the `public` folder as the WWW root, effectively placing all your application's files *outside* of the web root to help keep them secure. What you are experiencing is normal.

You'll have to either access your application from the `http://localhost/lara/blog/public` URL, or set up a virtual host URL (e.g. `http://testblog.dev`) that is pointed to the public folder. I do not develop on Windows/XAMPP so I cannot specifically tell you how to do that part.

Comment: Thank you very much. For increase benefits of this post, the following tutorial shows how to make virtual hosts on [tag:xampp] Apache: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Comment: You can also remove the public segment, @sємsєм , try [this](http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/).

Answer (score 4):

If you're running php > 5.4 you can serve the app using the builtin server from command prompt as well (for development purposes):

`php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer on [How to install Laravel via Laravel Installer on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451187/how-to-install-laravel-via-laravel-installer-on-windows)

or

http://goo.gl/uftcSo
for more details

Hope that helps.