# laravel when going to address I see folders, not starting the app

Tags: php, laravel

I am having xampp.

I installed laravel using composer, and there is directory 'laravel-test'

When I go to

http://[localhost]/laravel-test/

then I just see folders.

But when I go to some other - like http://[localhost]/darzelis/ which is written on codeigniter, it works. So it means xammp is working, but somehow laravel does not start.

I am going though http://laravel.com/docs/quick

and am stuck after creating first route - users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 does not work on Windows XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668734/laravel-4-does-not-work-on-windows-xampp)

Comment: now there be easier to find by the title, because when I googled did not find by my title :) and also stack ofverflow search did not find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, firstly Laravel's entry point is the /public/ directory. It contains the index.php file, try pointing your browser to http://[localhost]/laravel-test/public to check if things work.

Seeing the folders is also dependable on you server configuration, it's good to block that Apache behaviour.

Last but not least, deploying laravel in production environment , make sure that the users can access ONLY the public directory not the whole structure of your laravel folder (in your case laravel-test), which again is dependable on the Apache configuration (vhost doc root).

Comment: they should add this to the their tutorial, it was called quick start but wihtout knowing this, it was not quick at all :) thanks

Comment: navigating to /public displayed the index.php but can come with routing issues, as I experienced, as the laravel app hasn't started properly.

When I run either 'php -S localhost:8000 server.php' or 'php artisan serve', then the app starts properly and routing works.