# Laravel quick start example not run

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm new with Laravel and I'm trying to reproduce the [quickstart](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart) guide, but I don't get it to work.

I'm running local Apache Server in Linux (Debian)

This is my installation url: http://localhost/laravel_blog

I test adding to .htaccess, but not work

```
RewriteBase /laravel_blog/
```

My route is like is indicate in the quickstart guide

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()
    ]);
});
```

I read these stackoverflow answers, but the solution not worked for me.

[Laravel quick start guide route not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897504/laravel-quick-start-guide-route-not-working)

[laravel when going to address I see folders, not starting the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670966/laravel-when-going-to-address-i-see-folders-not-starting-the-app)

How can I get work the laravel route?

Comment: You have both laravel-4 and laravel-5 tags, please edit your question to exactly which version you're using, as they both are different. For the sake of it, there's even laravel-5.1 which is also different from 5. Small changes but if you're starting it will become confusing.

Comment: Also please state how you installed. The link you provided give different options on installing; git, composer or homestead?

Comment: I used composer and I'm using laravel 5.1

Comment: in the folder you created the project could you run `php artisan serve` and browse to http://localhost:8000

Comment: also add the error you're getting, what's not working?

Comment: After running php artisan serve and restart web browser now is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the folder you created the project could you run `php artisan serve` and browse to localhost:8000