# How to install Laravel via Laravel Installer on Windows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, installation, composer-php

I’m trying to install the Laravel Framework on Windows with the Laravel Installer method.

**In [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation) I found the following:**

> First, download the Laravel installer using Composer. Make sure to
>   place the “~/.composer/vendor/bin” directory in your PATH so the
>   laravel executable is found when you run the laravel command in your
>   terminal.

Now this PATH does not look familiar to me. Could you tell me the working path for Windows?

*BTW: I’m using WAMP. Composer is installed and updated.*

Comment: Forget about the Laravel installer and use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe) - it'll automatically install Composer system-wide (you don't have to fiddle with the PATH manually) and then you can just use it to install Laravel.

Comment: @AndréDaniel That Composer adds itself to the PATH on first installation is true, however I've always used the `composer create-project` command to install a fresh copy of Laravel and that took quite long to complete. IMO with the Laravel Installer it's a _breeze_. Did you try out the Installer yourself? It downloads the current release and just copies the files to the new dir each time you run the Installer command, instead of downloading Laravel over and over again. As Laravel has become more stable now, updates don't bubble up as fast as before, making this method work in the long run.

Answer (score 110):

## The PATH for Windows:

I’ve found the location where composer stores the Vendor files.

So instead of `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, on Windows the following path should be used:

```
C:\Users\<COMPUTER NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

How to install the Laravel Installer:
=======

I assume you have php and composer in your PATH already.

**First of all install the Laravel Installer.** Open a command prompt and enter:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

**Then update the PATH environment variable** via e.g. command prompt with admin privileges:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

// setx /M path "%path%;%appdata%\Composer\vendor\bin" (this may destroy your system)
```

## *%appdata% is added, so you don’t have to worry about adding your computer name.*

How to create a fresh Laravel Installation:

Now you should be able to run laravel commands in the command prompt.

To create a fresh laravel installation, open a command prompt in the directory of choice and enter:

```
laravel new name_of_directory
```

If everything went right, you should see the following message:

> Crafting application...
> Application ready! Build something amazing.

Comment: Creating a new project with the Laravel Installer took only a couple of seconds. The former composer installation method needed ages compared to the Installer. That's the reason I posted this Q&A to provide the steps required to make it work for others using Windows, as at the time of writing the Laravel documentation does not provide windows specific instructions.

Comment: In my case ``setx`` didn't work. I used ``set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`` instead

Comment: Be careful with setx as there is a limit on variable value length in CMD. If your path is already long enough it will be truncated (it's not truncated if you manually edit path using Windows UI). If the path is truncated and you still CMD open then just echo its previous value: `echo %path%`.

Comment: Appreciated ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Anyone facing difficulty with command lines, try this answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36216160/2407971

Comment: My Path was completely destroyed by "setx /M path "%path%;%appdata%\Composer\vendor\bin". Never make it at home.

Comment: **I updated this answer since a lot of users destroyed their systems with it!** What @Vic said is actually the right solution.

Answer (score 15):

Use Laragon (http://laragon.org/)
[image]

Install Laragon.

[image]

Use Laragon Menu to create project

[image]

Take you 5 minutes to have Laravel4 o Laravel5.
[image]

Launch Laragon Project

[image]

Laragon automatically create Virtual host for your project name ( project_name.me)

Hope it helps.

Source: https://innopy.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/laravel-windows/

Comment: Now a lot of things change with Laravel 5. Thank you for the detailed answer. I will look into this.

Answer (score 14):

If you are having trouble using the command prompt, use the GUI approach:

The path in Windows is:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

In the above path "UserName" is your user name that you are logged in your computer as. If you don't know your username, go here: http://library.queensu.ca/libguides/computers/windows-username-check.htm

Copy the above path, replace the "UserName" with your username.

Then go to your computer's environment variables. Here's how:

1. Right click on your Computer and go to properties
2. Go to Advanced system settings
3. Under Advanced Tab, Click on Environment Variables

[image]

Under `User Variables`, select `Path` and click `Edit`:

[image]

Put a semicolon at the end of the existing text and paste your path, example:`C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`. Press OK ...

[image]

Restart your command prompt and type `laravel` and hit enter. If the path was successfully set, you will see "Laravel Installer Version ... "

Answer (score 5):

**How to install Laravel on Windows using WAMP**

1. Install WAMP first.

I leave everything to default.

2. Enable OpenSSL and all required extensions in PHP.ini

After you installed WAMP, you need to do this. This is how you make sure OpenSSL is enabled:

On your right hand side of your taskbar, click WAMP and then choose PHP.ini.

And then find php_openssl, and then remove the semicolon in front of php_openssl.

And then, save. Close that file and now go to wamp manager again, and now enable OpenSSL there just to be safe.

After you do that, restart Wamp.

3. Install Composer

Go to https://getcomposer.org/ and download Windows installer.

The setup will ask for your PHP. if you install your WAMP in default setting, it will usually end up in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12.

If your installation is successful, by running composer on command prompt, you will see all kinds of info just by running that command.

If you can see it, that means your Composer installation is complete. Let’s move to the next one.

4. Make sure that your htppd.conf includes httpd-vhosts.conf

Now let’s make sure that your htppd.conf also includes httpd-vhosts.conf. This is beneficial if you want to make a pretty URL just like this one:

Instead of writing up localhost/mylaravel, it would be “nicer” to have that pretty URL, right?

Anyway, let’s go on.

Go to C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf and then open up httpd.conf.

After that, search for httpd-vhosts.conf and make sure that there is no ‘#’ (pound sign) in front of it. Save. After that restart Wamp just to be safe.

Now let’s begin the fun part: installing Laravel.

5. Install Laravel in specified folder

You usually want to install your Laravel in your www folder. (Obviously!)

So open up your command prompt, and then change directory to your WWW folder inside your wamp. For me it will be: C:\wamp\www

To change directory, just type cd c:\wamp\www

Basically you are changing folder to your www folder.

And then, you can install Laravel. Just use this in your command prompt:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name –prefer-dist
```

And then hit enter.

Just wait a while until it is finished downloading and installing.

6. Enable Laravel installer

If you want to use Laravel Installer, you have to run this command in your command prompt first:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Wait until… everything finished.

7. Create Virtual Host

Now let’s create your pretty URL. You have to go to C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra and then open up httpd-vhosts.conf.

After that, you just need to paste the following and change your laravel folder to appropriate ones.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “c:/wamp/www/mylaravel/public”
ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

In my case, I used mylaravel for my laravel installation. You have to change it to something else. For server name, you can change it to whatever you want. In my case, I am using laravel.dev. (You don’t want to use google.com because if you do, you won’t be able to open up Google).

Obviously, you have to save and then restart your WAMP again.

8. Update Windows Hosts file

After you have changed your virtual host, you need to change your host file.

Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and copy hosts and paste it on your Desktop. And click on the host file you have pasted on your Desktop. Open that up using Notepad.

Put this in that host file:

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.dev
```

Change laravel.dev into what you already decided in your virtual host file. For me, mine will be laravel.dev.

Copy the one that you modified just now and put it back into your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc folder.

You’re done!

Modified from this source: http://copygrammer.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-windows/ (my blog)

Comment: `composer global require "laravel/installer"` installs the laravel application

Answer (score 2):

Installing **Laravel framework** on window via **Laravel installer**:

1. make sure you have **composer** on your computer.
2. download the **Laravel installer** using **Composer** by typing following code in the command prompt:

composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

3. go to folder:

C:\Users\ {User Name} \AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor

4. copy the **vendor** folder and paste it into the folder (Destination folder) where you want to install Laravel project; for example, in folder D:\Test\Laravel.
5. after pasting, your folder structure look like this:
   D:\Test\Laravel\vendor
6. pressing down on Shift key and Right click on the folder vendor in your destination folder (D:\Test\Laravel\vendor), and choose "**open command window here**".
7. enter the command below:

   laravel new your_project_destination
8. after the command runs, you will see laravel folder in your_project_destination

Answer (score 1):

You can install laravel using Homestead box.

There are a few steps you need to follow.

Make sure that you have windows virtualization turned ON in your BIOS. This will save you a few hours if you are installing it for the first time.

You will also need to install Vagrant and Virtual Box before starting the installation of Homestead.

The main advantages of using Homestead is that it provides a Linux virtual machine where you can easily install packages. It does comes with a lot of packages installed.

http://deepdivetuts.com/installing-laravel-5-4-on-windows-machine-using-homestead

Answer (score 0):

> If you have not installed composer on your system get from [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).
>
> You will get this if you have composer on your system installed

[image: you will get this if you have composer on your system installed]

## Installing Laravel

#### Step 1: Installing **Laravel** globally.

Open **cmd** in Windows and enter this command.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

This will download the latest version.

[image: installing laravel]

> Check by entering the below command.

[image: version of laravel]

#### Step 2: Creating a new Laravel Project

Run the below command in **cmd**, `blog` is the name of my new project.

```
laravel new projectname
```

[image: new laravel project]

> That's it. Now you have your new project folder in the directory you have saved.